# Bitbucket is not showing the code difference that we committed

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Bitbucket throws an error message like below,

`Now that is a lot of code! There's simply too much in this diff for us to render it all.`

Can you please suggest a solution for this?

Thank you.
[image: Bitbucket_errro]

Comment: Please attach the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**
The number of lines in the file associated with the source in the diff view exceeds the page.max.diff.lines value (10000 by default).

**Resolution**

If the file associated with the diff contains more than 10000 lines, eg. 12384 lines, the following property will need to be added to the bitbucket.properties file and set to a value at least 1 greater than the number of lines:

page.max.diff.lines=12385

If the file contains less than 10000 lines, and this warning is displayed, then the default has already been updated to a value less than 10000. Check your bitbucket.properties file for this property.

Bitbucket Server will always need to be **restarted** for changes on the bitbucket.properties file to take effect.

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/the-diff-for-this-file-is-too-large-to-render-803604636.html